# Does flash only compile what it needs to? Or does it always 'rebuild all'?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

new to Flash -

I have a main FLA that loads and runs my entire flash/AS3 project. It always seems to take the same amount of time (~3 minutes) no matter what code has changed. Does Flash have the concept of makefiles? Is it always rebuilding all of my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you build within the Flash IDE, it builds the entire fla. For large projects, I break the project into different fla's, build them separately, and have the main fla dynamically load in other swf's.

Answer (score 1):

If you trigger the compiler manually, you can specify the "-incremental" flag or use the fcsh (Flex Compiler Shell). I would never compile a serious project from within the Flash IDE.

Comment: can you elaborate? If I don't split up the main fla into different ones will this approach do what I want it to do? I know the Flash IDE is awful, but why specifically wouldn't you compile within it?

Comment: Since you can not control how the compiler is invoked at a fine grained level. I would export as SWC from the Flash IDE and then continue development with FlexBuilder for instance, using assets of that SWC.

Answer (score 0):

In the Flash IDE it will always compile from the ground up.

In Flex, I believe the default behavior is to only compile MXML files that have *changed*. But I suppose it varies by project settings.